# Ubuntu apt-get update vs upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, apt, update, aptitude

I have a VPS with Ubuntu Server 12.04 and I want maximal stability of my server, which's main purpose is a webserver.

What are difference between `Update` and `Upgrade`? I can't understand difference. As I understand `Upgrade` is upgrading version of package of some software product and if this upgraded software have, for example, some API change and my code can become incompatible with that update I will run into problems. But since this is only small version change compared to big version change using `dist-upgrade` most times those upgrades will be compatible with my code. Do I understand it right?

Second small question is `sudo apt-get update` is the same as if I run `sudo aptitude` and install all Security updates? I love `aptitude`, it is something like Windows Updates, that's why I choose Ubuntu Server.

Comment: `man apt-get` is a useful resource to read - really.

Comment: @lain has an elegant way of saying `rtm`.

Comment: For the record, most Linux distribution have package management software as powerful as `apt|aptitude`. Not only "Ubuntu server"

Answer (score 14):

Simply:

`apt-get update` will **update** your local copies of your repositories' package data, such as available versions and dependencies.

- This is needed to check whether any updates are present.
- It doesn't actually **upgrade** packages.

`apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get dist-upgrade` will **upgrade** packages.

- The former runs general system upgrades
- The latter will apply higher level patches such as kernel upgrades.
- Check [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194651/why-use-apt-get-upgrade-instead-of-apt-get-dist-upgrade) for a detailed look into `upgrade` vs `dist-upgrade`

For a detailed discussion of `aptitude` vs `apt-get`, [read this AskUbuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1743/is-aptitude-still-considered-superior-to-apt-get).

Comment: One important note is that `dist-upgrade` will put your system in sync with the latest available versions of packages for the distribution you've selected, which means that it can downgrade packages in some cases.